# Angular 2 RC.0 not working in IE 11

Tags: angularjs

I have these packages importing:
     angular/common
     angular/compiler
     angular/core
    angular/http
    angular/platform-browser
    angular/platform-browser-dynamic

Beta 17 was working with IE shim:
    node_modules/angular2/es6/prod/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js
    node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js
    node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js

What is the equivalent of this for RC?

Answer (score 1):

The order matters, it should be in this order

```
node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.min.js
node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
```

Comment: Is this still true for RC.5?